# Bind dropdown value to a bean in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a drop downdown box and trying to bind the selected account number to fromAccount inside the transfer bean.

I am seeing the value as null in the controller.

```
            <select class="form-control" th:field="${customer.transferBean.fromAccount}">
            <option
                    th:each="fromAccount: ${customer.accountBean}"
                    th:value="${fromAccount.accountNum}"
                    th:text="${fromAccount.accountNum}" ></option>
            </select>
```

controller code:

```
@PostMapping("/accounttransfer")
public String accountTransfer(@Valid CustomerBean customerBean, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model)
```

Not sure what i am missing. I am using spring boot and thymeleaf for html.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong syntax

```
"th:field="${customer.transferBean.fromAccount}"
```

for specifying bind field, you should use `*{}` not `${}` and only combined with `th:object` on parent or ansestor level.

More details on bindingm you can find in Thymeleaf docs

Comment: Thank you. You were right I was using the wrong syntax.